# changing y axis numbers in different population number

Tags: r

I have a data frame named `mydata` which contains population for different `country`.

```
df<- data_frame(age= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), gender = "male", 
population =c(180,160,130,140,150,160,170,90,85,80,75,70,65,60,40), country = 1)
                
df1<- data_frame(age= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), gender = "female", 
population =c(160,150,120,130,140,150,160,80,75,70,65,60,55,50,30),country  = 1)

df2<- data_frame(age= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), gender = "male", 
population =c(80,77,66,65,69,69,54,50,44,40,38,29,20,12,8), country = 2)

df3<- data_frame(age= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), gender = "female",
population =c(76,70,61,63,60,51,41,39,37,33,30,28,23,22,10), country = 2)

df4<- data_frame(age= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), gender = "male", 
 population =c(29,27,30,26,24,22,20,18,16,14,12,10,8,6,4), country = 3)

df5<- data_frame(age= c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), gender = "female",
population =c(28,24,20,22,23,24,22,21,20,18,16,13,12,10,6), country = 3)


mydata<- rbind(df,df1,df2,df3,df4,df5)
```

in the code below, I got a population pyramid for three countries. because of different number of population in each country, my population pyramids are different visually and not comparable, how can I change y axis so that I have a comparable population pyramid?

```
ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=age, y = ifelse(gender == "male", -population, population), fill=gender)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~country) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not keep posting duplicates of this question.  I see it 3 times over the last day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(pop_rel = population / sum(population)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=age, y = ifelse(gender == "male", -pop_rel, pop_rel), fill=gender)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    facet_wrap(~country) +
    coord_flip()
```

which plots population relative to that country's population:

[image: relative population]

(Data used:)

```
mydata <- structure(list(age = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70), gender = c("male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female"), population = c(180, 160, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 90, 85, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 40, 160, 150, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55, 50, 30, 80, 77, 66, 65, 69, 69, 54, 50, 44, 40, 38, 29, 20, 12, 8, 76, 70, 61, 63, 60, 51, 41, 39, 37, 33, 30, 28, 23, 22, 10, 29, 27, 30, 26, 24, 22, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 28, 24, 20, 22, 23, 24, 22, 21, 20, 18, 16, 13, 12, 10, 6), country = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -90L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @ ktiu why your code do not get same output anymore?

Comment: Is this output what you were looking for? I'm plotting another variable, `pop_rel` that I calculated by dividing the demographic numbers by the country's total population.

Comment: your suggested code is correct but when I do again I do not get same result

Comment: Make sure you copy and execute my "data used" and then my code. Try a fresh session / project in R. I'm confident that I included all dependencies in the code.

Comment: I tried but it does not work.  I  got confused. is there any alternative code?

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: I am getting my first output in my question not the output of your suggested code. actually the three pyramids are still visually different.

Comment: I'm convinced that this is not an issue with my code, I cannot help you to run it properly.